# Mercurial : hook to limit pulls to one branch only

Tags: mercurial, hook, pull

I'm stumped trying to ensure that a deployment repository only updates a specific branch off the central Mercurial server.

Specifically I need to ensure that anyone pulling changes to the deployment repository is doing the equivalent of

```
hg pull -b deployment <central-repo-url>
```

rather than

```
hg pull <central-repo-url>
```

I assume I need to use the `pre-pull` hook, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally, same technique, but more user-friendly way;

[ACL extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension), in which you define [acl.deny.branches] and [acl.allow.branches] for your workflow

Comment: Tom's answer was hugely helpful; but the ACL extension does seem to be the simplest solution. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, yes, i didn't think of that at all. I think of ACL being something you use to control pushes into a repository, but of course there's nothing stopping it being used for pulls. Clean and configurable.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing might be to define an [alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) in that repository's hgrc that defines `pull` as `pull -b deployment`. Then, any attempt to pull will do what you want. However, it would be very easy to screw this up in such a way that would make any attempt to pull an infinite loop.

I would suggest a [`pretxnchangegroup` hook](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EnsureCommitPolicy). That lets you examine the changesets that are being imported, and reject them if you don't like them. I suspect that the rule you want to enforce is that the tip should always be on the deployment branch (the changegroup might drag in changesets from other branches which have been merged into deployment, but the tip should always come from deployment). That would be a hook like:

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit.deployment = hg log -r tip --template '{branch}\n' | grep '^deployment$'
```